# why does my JList get temporary focus?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jlist

I've a `JList`, in some panels hierarchy, I am not been able to change selection through key <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> events and noticed that I don't get any key events to my `JList`, so I started investigating the focus management of my `Swing` hierarchy by adding these lines:

```
mJList.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("focusLost to "+e.getOppositeComponent());
        //mJList.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("focusGained");
    }
});
```

In the beginning, I noticed that some of my buttons were gaining focus few milliseconds after my `JList` gained it, so I made all those buttons unfocusable, and then I am getting this weird result, my `JList` is losing focus to... **null**?!?!

```
focusGained
focusLost to null
```

then I added the line which is commented out in focusLost method to regain the focus whenever it gets lost, but I believe its a very bad solution for long terms, so my questions are :

1. Why did my `JList` only get a temporal focus and if its not the case, then why would it be forced to give up on it for `null` ?
2. How to fix it in a proper(good practice) way ?

Comment: Why not use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) ? This is not bound to focus related issues like `KeyListener`s are, to some extend. This post regarding [Motion Using Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/), can give you more insight for each approach, by @camickr :-)

Answer (score 1):

please can you explain your issue on this SSCCE, otherwise post your own

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Testing extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList list = new JList(listModel);
    private JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(list);
    private JButton btn1 = new JButton("Reset Model with freeze");
    private JButton btn2 = new JButton("Reset Model with change selection");
    private int xX = 0;

    public Testing() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 19; x++) {
            listModel.addElement("" + x);
            xX++;
        }
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                listModel.removeAllElements();
                // caused locking GUI for long time in the case 
                // that Item count is more than 999 Items
                for (int x = 0; x < 19; x++) {
                    listModel.addElement("" + (x + xX));
                    xX++;
                }
            }
        });
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //list.clearSelection();
                if (list.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
                    list.setSelectedIndex(1);
                }
                listModel.removeAllElements();
                for (int x = 0; x < 19; x++) {
                    listModel.addElement("" + (x + xX));
                    xX++;
                }
                list.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        });
        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btn1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(btn2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setLocation(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                list.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        });
        list.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                System.out.println("focusLost to " + e.getOppositeComponent());
                //mJList.requestFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                System.out.println("focusGained");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Testing().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i have too much graphics and a very big hierarchy of panels in my project so i cant really produce a SSCCE, and your SSCE doesnt reproduce what i was talking about...

Comment: @OfekRon it's _your job_ to find the error - extracting a SSCCE is an effective way to lead you to a solution, either you find it yourself or someone can help you. Without, there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: @Ofek Ron  then your answer isn't answerable, my intentions were to put there plain focus_recycle without shadowing consumers, wild shot to the dark ---> remove/disable all your setting for setFocusable(true/false)